# How to configure the find command to run in a Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I am trying to run the following find command in a Linux shell script. When I run the command in the terminal, it successfully finds all the files with the extension `.mp4` from the specified folder, and copies them to a temp folder.

```
find /datadrive/reports/ -name \*.mp4 -exec cp {} 
/datadrive/reports/video_tmp/ \;
```

However, when I run it in my `file_mover.sh`

Code:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/find /datadrive/reports/ -name '\*.mp4' -exec cp {} 
/datadrive/reports/video_tmp/ \;
done
MAILTO=root
```

Output:

```
./file_mover.sh: line 2: /datadrive/reports/: Is a directory.
```

I think I'm missing syntax somewhere in the script, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'\*.mp4'` is different from `\*.mp4`

Comment: And the `PATH` assignment is breaking things. And the `done` makes no syntactic sense.

Comment: That invocation of `find` doesn't return any useful information, so no need to attempt to assign it to a variable.

Comment: BTW, if this is a GNU platform (likely, with the Linux tag), you can use `cp -t` to be able to pass multiple filenames to just one `cp` command, rather than needing to run `cp` once per file.

Comment: If all the files are in that one folder and not located in subfolders, you don't need find at all: `cp -t /datadrive/reports/video_tmp  /datadrive/reports/*.mp4`

Comment: The question is not clear. The first code is not doing the same thing as the second. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It looks like your script is based on a crontab, which causes some of the confusion - a crontab is not a general purpose script template.

Comment: You can also pipe to xargs to avoid the -exec syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a perfectly valid script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /datadrive/reports/ -name '*.mp4' -exec cp -t /datadrive/reports/video_tmp/ '{}' +
```

Note the changes:

- We aren't trying to assign to `PATH`. This is a variable with special meaning (it determines where programs are found), so reassigning it generally messes things up.
- We aren't using a backslash inside single quotes. `-name \*.mp4` is legal as a match for all files ending in `.mp4`. `-name '*.mp4'` is legal for the same purpose. You can't combine the two and have it still mean what you want.
- By using `cp -t dest source1 source2 ...`, we're allowing `find` to only run `cp` the shortest number of times needed to put the destination filenames on the command line.

There's also no point to assigning `SHELL` and `MAILTO`; they're meaningful in a crontab (and some other specific/narrow circumstances), but not in a general-purpose script.

Comment: I had been using some existing legacy code I found on our system, and saw PATH used when a command is run in the script and assumed that was how it worked. But reformatting my script to work as you've shown has fixed my issue. Thank you very much!